# ASP.NET MVC C# observ list and hold removed and added items

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, observable

I have a class which looks like:

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _areaCollection;
private List<string> _removedAreas;
private List<string> _addedAreas;

public Constructor()
{
    _areaCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    _areaCollection.CollectionChanged += AreaCollectionChanged;
    _removedAreas = new List<string>();
    _addedAreas = new List<string>();
}

public IEnumerable<string> Areas { get { return _areaCollection; } }

public IEnumerable<string> AddedAreas
{
    get { return _addedAreas; }
}

public IEnumerable<string> RemovedAreas
{
    get { return _removedAreas; }
}

public void DisableArea(string areaAlias)
{
    if (_areaCollection.Contains(areaAlias))
        _areaCollection.Remove(areaAlias);
}

public void EnableArea(string areaAlias)
{
    if (!_areaCollection.Contains(areaAlias))
        _areaCollection.Add(areaAlias);
}

private void SectionCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
    {
        var item = e.NewItems.Cast<string>().First();

        if (_addedAreas.Contains(item) == false)
        {
            _addedAreas.Add(item);
        }
    }
    else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
    {
        var item = e.OldItems.Cast<string>().First();

        if (_removedAreas.Contains(item) == false)
        {
            _removedAreas.Add(item);    
        }

    }
}
```

Then in my controller on a Update actionresult I call a method to update the properties:

```
 private bool UpdateProperties(IUser current, IUser update, out IUser result)
 {
    result = current;

    // Update areas
    ...

    return true;
 }
```

So here I want the following result:

1. `_areaCollection` of the result contains the updated list
2. `_removedAreas` contains the areas which were removed based on the update
3. `_addedAreas` contains the areas which were added based on the update

But I am stuck on this.

Comment: If everything is private, what's the purpose of `ObservableCollection`? Why don't you just encapsulate your logic inside Disable/Enable methods? Also, it's truly difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve, the question is not clear at all. What is not working?

Comment: Forgot my 2 public get properties for removed and added areas. I want to hold the removed and added areas so I can update the database easily. So first I remove the areas by looking into the RemovedAreas property and then do an insert by looking on the AddedAreas property.

Comment: My question still remains, why don't you just use a `List` instead of an `ObservableCollection`, and put `_addedAreas.Add(item);` and `_removedAreas.Add(item);` inside `EnableArea`/`DisableArea` methods? This will simplify your class.

Comment: Ok but then what, how do I sync my areaCollection of 2 objects and have the result like I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are approaching your problem in the wrong way. From what I understand what you want is to know the differences between two collections. For this purpose you do not need `ObservableCollection` at all, you just need to filter which elements are removed and which are added.

Assuming `current` and `updated` both contains a read/write property called `Areas`:

```
var updatedSet = new HashSet<string>(updated.Areas);
var currentSet = new HashSet<string>(current.Areas);

var added = updatedSet.Where(a => !currentSet.Contains(a));
var removed = currentSet.Where(a => !updatedSet.Contains(a));
current.Areas = updated.Areas;
```

If you really need to keep your `Areas` property read-only you may change the last line with the following code:

```
foreach(var item in added)
    current.EnableArea(item);
foreach(var item in removed)
    current.DisableArea(item);
```

Which is really inefficient.

Comment: I also use these methods to only edit the areas instead of updating the entire object. But maybe its something to think over.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have created a `UpdateArea()` method where I do the magic and removed the 2 other methods.